# C++ if statement reordering

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, if-statement

In my C++ (lets say this is gcc ) I do the following:

```
bool prevCurve;
bool curveInside;
bool prevCurveIn
if (!(prevCurve && curveInside == prevCurveIn)){
...
}
```

Will compiler optimize it like that:

```
bool prevCurve;
bool curveInside;
bool prevCurveIn
if (!prevCurve || curveInside != prevCurveIn){
...
}
```

Comment: Why would it be optimization?

Comment: This depends on your compiler, on your optimization settings, and on where and when the booleans get their values (i.e., if one of them is constant in your current scope, it may entirely *disappear* from the equation).

Comment: @LaszloPapp: in the first case both parts of the comparison must be checked, in the 'optimized' line ideally only one.

Comment: @Jongware: what do you mean? It is three operations either way: one comparison, one negation, and one OR/AND.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: no it's not :) In the second example, if `prevCurve` is `false`, the second part does not need checking.

Comment: @Jongware: you could say the same about the first since the right side of && would not be evaulated if prevCurve is true, so what is the gain again?

Comment: @Icjury: no, he does not.

Comment: In the first example, the entire sub-expression must be evaluated because of the `&` AND. Only after that, the negation is done on its result and then evaluated. For the OR in the second, it's not necessary.

Comment: @Jongware: A && B => it is 0 if A is 0, there is no need to evaluate B, and then the negation is 1, so you have two operetaions, just like in the latter case. I do not see any optimization. They are "optimized" for different values (true or false).

Comment: @LaszloPapp: you sure? **A AND B** is only true of *both* are true. What you state is **A OR B** -- either one, or both true (which can be short-circuited if A is already true).

Comment: Forget my last sentence. They are equally optimized. But the ones before still holds true. I cannot understand what optimization you are speaking about. Sometimes (not in this case), the OR variant could be even worse if you have to do two negations. This does not matter here with "==" and "!=", but if the case is slightly different, it is even slower.

Comment: Jongware you seem to be mixed up on operator short circuiting in C - if `prevCurve` is false, then in the expression `prevCurve && X`, `X` is not evaluated. The result of the expression is determined to be `false` if the left operand is `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. When evaluating this expression:

```
if (!(prevCurve && curveInside == prevCurveIn)){
```

The standard requires that `prevCurve` be evaluated fully including any side-effects before the evaluation of the remainder of the expression. The operator '&&' introduces a sequence point. In the case of the equivalent:

```
if (!prevCurve || curveInside != prevCurveIn){
```

The operator `||` also introduces a sequence point.

It is theoretically possible that a compiler might generate identical code in the two cases but even if it does this is not optimisation. Leaving aside the possibility of optimisation based on other considerations, the code in each case will execute a similar sequence of instructions with exactly the same result. The standard requires that this be so.

Comment: To clarify, the standard requires that the statement block following the `if` is either executed in both cases, or not executed in both cases; it imposes no requirements on what assembly code is generated, or how long it takes to run.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: But it does impose requirements on both the ordering of evaluation and whether the right hand side is evaluated for both `||` and `&&`.

Comment: Yep, although there are no observable effects of that evaluation in this particular example (unless the variables are volatile or uninitialized). I meant to say that the standard doesn't require a similar sequence of instructions to be generated, even though the two expressions are guaranteed to have exactly equivalent observable behaviour

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely up to your compiler and the code around, but this would not be an optimization after all considering the most common instruction sets out there.

The reason is that you have three operations to be executed either way:

- one evaluation, either variable or negated variable
- negation
- OR/AND

The order might be different, but these points have to be executed. I am not aware of any instruction set where one can be optimized over the other.

As written in the comment, the compiler could even optimize out varibles if they have constant values, what optimization options you use for gcc, which version of gcc, which architecture, different platforms, etc.

The best way would be to compare the assembler outputs that you can generate with:

```
gcc -S main.cpp
```